Could the characterization in terms of full idempotents be used to show that Morita equivalence is symmetric?
Two rings $R$ and $S$ are said to be Morita equivalent if the categories of right $R$-modules and right $S$-modules (or equivalently, of left $R$-modules and left $S$-modules) are equivalent. It is known that $S$ is Morita equivalent to $R$ if and only if $S$ is isomorphic to the corner ring $eM_n(R)e$ for some positive integer $n$ and some full idempotent $e \in M_n(R)$ (i.e., an idempotent $e$ for which $M_n(R)eM_n(R)=M_n(R)$).
It is obvious that Morita equivalence is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive (using the "equivalent categories of modules" definition).
For the equivalent characterization in terms of full idempotents, while that is easily seen to be reflexive ($R$ is isomorphic to $1M_1(R)1=M_1(R)$ and $1$ is obviously a full idempotent) and transitive (if $S$ is isomorphic to $eM_n(R)e$ and $T$ is isomorphic to $fM_m(S)f$ for some full idempotents $e$ and $f$ in $M_n(R)$ and $M_m(S)$ respectively, then applying an isomorphism $S \cong eM_n(R)e$ to all the entries of $f$ gives an idempotent $mn \times mn$ block matrix $g$ for which $T$ is isomorphic to $gM_{mn}(R)g$ and $g$ is easily seen to be a full idempotent in $M_{mn}(R)$), it is not obvious that the relation is symmetric.
So, given an isomorphism $S \cong eM_n(R)e$ for some positive integer $n$ and some full idempotent $e \in M_n(R)$, how could one find some positive integer $m$ and some full idempotent $f \in M_m(S)$ for which $R$ is isomorphic to $fM_m(S)f$?
For the "classic" example of Morita equivalence (the one between $R$ and $M_n(R)$ where the corresponding full idempotent $e$ is the identity matrix), one could just let $m=1$ and $f$ be the $n \times n$ idempotent matrix where the top left entry (or any arbitrary entry on the main diagonal) is $1$ and all other entries are $0$.
Regardless of how $m$ and $f$ are constructed from $n$ and $e$, it is not expected that applying the same construction twice would lead back to the original pair (that is, applying the same construction twice could produce a pair $(n', e')$ different from $(n, e)$ for which $S$ is also isomorphic to $e'M_{n'}(R)e'$).

We know $S={\rm End}{-R}(e R^n)$.  We also know the natural map $R\to {\rm End}{S-}(e R^n)$ is injective, as $e$ is full.  If we could show it is surjective, then we would have $R={\rm End}{S-}(e R^n)$ which in turn would equal $fM_m(S)f$ for some integer $m$ and idempotent $f$, if $e R^n$ is f.g. projective over $S$ (or equivalently $eM_n(R)$ is f.g. projective over $S$).  I am not sure why $f$ would be full though.  There are three holes in this argument: 1) Is the map $R\to {\rm End}{S-}(e R^n)$ surjective? 2) Is  $eM_n(R)$ f.g. projective? 3)Is $f$ full?
